# Increment column value by 1 while insert..select join

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have 3 tables table_1, table_2 and table_3.

I am trying to insert data into table_3 (some rows are already present in this table) with join from table_1 and table_2.

`table_3` has the following columns:

```
unique_id  - its unique id needs to be increment by 1 from its last value
client_key - should get from table_1.client_key
xcolumn    - should get from table_2.xcolumn
xxcolumn   - this column value depend on table_3.xcolumn (below I mentioned which value should be here) 
         if table_3.xcolumn contains any of this value (purchase some things,purchase) xxcolumn should be PURCHASE 
         if table_3.xcolumn contains any of this value (cash advance,ATM,promo cashing) xxcolumn should be CASH
         if table_3.xcolumn contains any of this value (promo,promo deal) xxcolumn should be PROMO
         if table_3.xcolumn doest not contains any above value then xxcolumn should be OTHER
xycolumn   - this column value depend on table_3.xxcolumn (below I mentioned which value should be here)
         if table_3.xxcolumn is PURCHASE xycolumn should be 1 
         if table_3.xxcolumn is CASH xycolumn should be 2
         if table_3.xxcolumn is PROMO xycolumn should be 3
         if table_3.xxcolumn is OTHER xycolumn should be 4           
ycolumn    - should get from table_2.ycolumn
```

I have tried below query for insert:

```
insert into table_3 (unique_id, client_key, xcolumn, xxcolumn, xycolumn, ycolumn)  
    select
        (select max(unique_id) + 1 
         from table_3),
        table_1.client_key, table_2.xcolumn,
        'cash', 1, table_2.ycolumn 
    from 
        table_2  
    inner join 
        table_1 on table_2.client_id = table_1.client_id;
```

but for unique_id I am not able to increase its value by 1 while   join if more than one row get (only incrementing one time not for every row).

Also I am not able to figure out how to get xxcolumn,xycolumn value.

For ref. I have created sql fiddle with table_1,table_2,,table_3

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a48477/2

Comment: Why aren't you using auto increment fields for your primary keys? The query in your SQL Fiddle doesn't make sense.

Comment: Also, keys shouldn't have leading zeros.

Comment: Table DDL is already defined , i can not change it and unique_id is not set auto increament   while creating. that's why i am taking manual approach

Comment: @SloanThrasher Sorry i did not get you, zeros ??

Comment: Cannot change schema --> warm up your resume.